# Skype for Business on Mac disconnects with screen saver action

Tags: skype-for-business

I am a corporate user and our Mac IT team has not been able to solve this very long-standing and frustrating issue with Skype for Business (S4B).

My normal configuration is two external monitors attached via DisplayPort with the lid closed and power always connected.

Soon after my external monitors sleep S4B disconnects. Attempts by colleagues to send me a message via Skype do not work because my status is "offline." When I return and unlock the screens S4B is waiting for me to push the "Continue" button and it reconnects. I do not have to reenter a username or password.

My suspicion is S4B erroneously believes my machine is about to go to sleep when the monitors go to sleep. My machine is not going to sleep, it is configured to remain on whenever it is plugged in, even when the lid is closed. I am able to remote into my machine when away from it and it is always running and available, the machine has not gone to sleep, only the monitors have.

I'm not the only one here that experiences this, most of my colleagues who using Macs experience the same or a similar issue (unwanted disconnects of Skype for Business). These are a wide variety of macOS machine types and vintages (all are laptops).

Sure would love to know if there is a solution to this problem!!

*--Paul Fischer*

> I'm currently using version 16.21.65 of Skype for Business for Mac on macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6. This is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012) system. Apparently our Skype servers are a mixture of CU6 and CU7 versions.

Comment: can  you post a screenshot of the "Continue" button screen?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to macOS users requiring mobility set to: True on the Skype Server backend. Take a look[at this MS KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4487828/can-t-automatically-sign-in-to-skype-for-business-for-mac-after-enable)

Comment: Thanks for the KB link, I'll forward it to our IT folks. I suspect, however, that they will not want to enable that feature, for security reasons. :( p.s. I'll attach a screenshot of the "continue" screen, it's the same thing you see when you start S4B.